# sql query questions based on w3 schools

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

List customers for each category and the total of order placed by that customer in a given category. In the query show three columnm: CategoryName, CustomerName, and TotalOrders (which is price * quantity for orders for a given customer in a given category). Sort this data in descending order by TotalOrders.

Comment: Did you have a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Please show your attempt and let us know what problems you are having.  Hint, you need to use `group by`...

Answer (score 0):

should be this  ...

```
select category, customer, sum(price*quantity)  as TotalOrders
from yourTable 
group by category, customer
order by TotalOrders desc;
```